# ¿como envio un json y un multipart desde postman?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, postman

Buenos días estoy realizando un crud con spring boot,
el problema es esta en como esta recibiendo los multipart, que no lo estoy haciendo bien en el controlador, cree una entidad para que guarde la ruta de donde se van a guardar unos archivos pdf, y hice en el controlador una solicitud de tipo post para crear el usuario el problema es que no he podido hacer el envio del json y el multipart desde postman para probar si funciona, sale siempre esto,
en resumen el problema esta en como estoy enviando la data.

[image: error de postman]

este es mi entidad:

```
package com.inventarioohsjd.inventarioohsjdapi.modelos;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Data
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "cen_cos")
    private String cenCos; 

    @Column(name = "grupo_area_pertenece")
    private String grupoAreaPertence;

    private String nombre;

    private int documento;

    private String cargo;
    
    @Column(name = "ruta_pdf_acta_entrega")
    private String rutaActaEntrega;

    @Column(name = "ruta_pdf_formato_activo")
    private String rutaFormatoActivo;

    @Column(name = "fecha_asignacion")
    private String fechaAsignacion;

    @Column(name = "fecha_compra")
    private String fechaCompra;

    private String observacion;

    private String estado;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonManagedReference
    private EquipoSoftware equipoSoftware;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private EquipoHardware equipoHadware;

}
```

mi servicio:

```
package com.inventarioohsjd.inventarioohsjdapi.servicios;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.inventarioohsjd.inventarioohsjdapi.modelos.Usuario;

@Service
public class UsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;

    public Page<Usuario> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return usuarioRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }

    public Usuario findById(Long id) {
        return usuarioRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void eliminarUsuario(Long usuarioId) {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findById(usuarioId).orElse(null);
        if (usuario != null) {
            usuarioRepository.delete(usuario);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void guardarUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        usuarioRepository.save(usuario);
    }

}
```

y mi controlador:

```
package com.inventarioohsjd.inventarioohsjdapi.controladores;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import com.inventarioohsjd.inventarioohsjdapi.modelos.Usuario;
import com.inventarioohsjd.inventarioohsjdapi.servicios.UsuarioService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/inventario-api/v1")
public class UsuarioControlador {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    private final String uploadDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "upload";

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> obtenerUsuarios(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") int pagina) {
        Map<String, Object> mensaje = new HashMap<>();
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pagina, 4);

        Page<Usuario> usuarios = usuarioService.findAll(pageable);

        if (usuarios.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        }
        mensaje.put("usuarios", usuarios);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(mensaje);
    }

    @GetMapping("/eliminar")
    public ResponseEntity<?> eliminarUsuario(@RequestParam Long id) {
        Map<String, String> mensaje = new HashMap<>();
        mensaje.put("mensaje", "Usuario eliminado correctamente");
        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findById(id);
        if (usuario != null) {
            try {
                usuarioService.eliminarUsuario(usuario.getId());
                System.out.println(usuario.toString());
                return ResponseEntity.ok(mensaje);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mensaje.put("mensaje", "Error al eliminar el usuario con el id " + id.toString());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(mensaje);
            }
        } else {
            mensaje.put("mensaje", "Usuario no encontrado con el id " + id.toString());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(mensaje);
        }
    }

    @PostMapping("/crear-usuario")
    public ResponseEntity<?> crearUsuario(@RequestBody Usuario usuario,
            @RequestParam("archivoActaEntrega") MultipartFile archivoActaEntrega,
            @RequestParam("archivoFormatoActivo") MultipartFile archivoFormatoActivo) {
            System.out.println(archivoActaEntrega.getOriginalFilename());
        Map<String, String> mensaje = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            if (archivoActaEntrega != null && !archivoActaEntrega.isEmpty()) {
                String filePathActaEntrega = uploadFile(archivoActaEntrega);
                usuario.setRutaActaEntrega(filePathActaEntrega);
            }

            if (archivoFormatoActivo != null && !archivoFormatoActivo.isEmpty()) {
                String filePathFormatoActivo = uploadFile(archivoFormatoActivo);
                usuario.setRutaFormatoActivo(filePathFormatoActivo);
            }

            // Guardar el usuario en la base de datos, incluyendo las rutas de los archivos
            usuarioService.guardarUsuario(usuario);

            mensaje.put("mensaje", "Usuario creado exitosamente");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(mensaje);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensaje.clear();
            mensaje.put("error", "Error al crear el usuario: " + e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(mensaje);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/editar-usuario")
    public ResponseEntity<?> editarUsuario(@RequestParam Long id, @RequestBody Usuario usuarioEditado) {
        Map<String, String> mensaje = new HashMap<>();
        Usuario usuario = usuarioService.findById(id);
        if (usuario != null) {
            usuario.setCenCos(usuarioEditado.getCenCos());
            usuario.setDocumento(usuarioEditado.getDocumento());
            usuario.setGrupoAreaPertence(usuarioEditado.getGrupoAreaPertence());
            usuario.setNombre(usuarioEditado.getNombre());
            usuario.setDocumento(usuarioEditado.getDocumento());
            usuario.setCargo(usuarioEditado.getCargo());
            usuario.setFechaAsignacion(usuarioEditado.getFechaAsignacion());
            usuario.setFechaCompra(usuarioEditado.getFechaCompra());
            usuario.setObservacion(usuarioEditado.getObservacion());
            usuario.setEstado(usuarioEditado.getEstado());
            usuario.setEquipoSoftware(usuarioEditado.getEquipoSoftware());
            usuario.setEquipoHadware(usuarioEditado.getEquipoHadware());
            try {
                mensaje.put("mensaje", "Usuario editado exitosamente");
                usuarioService.guardarUsuario(usuario);
                return ResponseEntity.ok(mensaje);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mensaje.clear();
                mensaje.put("error", "Error al editar el usuario: " + e.getMessage());
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(mensaje);
            }

        } else {
            mensaje.put("mensaje", "Usuario no encontrado con el id " + id.toString());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(mensaje);
        }

    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        // Verificar si el archivo está vacío
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            return "Archivo no válido";
        }

        try {
            // Obtener el nombre original del archivo
            String originalFileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

            // Generar un nombre de archivo único usando el nombre original y la marca de
            // tiempo actual
            String uniqueFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + originalFileName;

            // Construir la ruta completa del archivo dentro de la carpeta "upload"
            String filePath = uploadDir + File.separator + uniqueFileName;

            // Guardar el archivo en la carpeta especificada
            file.transferTo(new File(filePath));

            // Devolver la ruta donde se guarda el archivo
            return filePath;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Manejar cualquier error que ocurra durante el proceso de carga
            return "Error al cargar el archivo";
        }
    }

    // Sirve para obtener el pdf solicitado solo es vizualización
    @GetMapping("/obtenerPdf/{fileName:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName) throws MalformedURLException {
        // Obtener la ruta completa del archivo solicitado
        String filePath = uploadDir + File.separator + fileName;

        // Cargar el archivo como recurso
        Resource resource = new UrlResource(Paths.get(filePath).toUri());

        // Verificar si el archivo existe y es accesible
        if (resource.exists() && resource.isReadable()) {
            // Devolver el archivo como un flujo de datos binarios con el tipo MIME adecuado
            return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                    .body(resource);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No se pudo cargar el archivo");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

realice un cambio en lo que solicita el controlador de @RequestBody a @ModelAttribue y en el postman envie cada llave por ejemplo el nombre por separado, tambien modifique upload para que no fuera una solicitud post sino un metodo normal.

```
@PostMapping("/crear-usuario")
    public ResponseEntity<?> crearUsuario(@ModelAttribute Usuario usuario,
            @RequestParam("archivoActaEntrega") MultipartFile archivoActaEntrega,
            @RequestParam("archivoFormatoActivo") MultipartFile archivoFormatoActivo) {
        Map<String, String> mensaje = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            if (archivoActaEntrega != null && !archivoActaEntrega.isEmpty()) {
                String filePathActaEntrega = uploadFile(archivoActaEntrega);
                usuario.setRutaActaEntrega(filePathActaEntrega);
            }

            if (archivoFormatoActivo != null && !archivoFormatoActivo.isEmpty()) {
                String filePathFormatoActivo = uploadFile(archivoFormatoActivo);
                usuario.setRutaFormatoActivo(filePathFormatoActivo);
            }

            // Guardar el usuario en la base de datos, incluyendo las rutas de los archivos
            usuarioService.guardarUsuario(usuario);

            mensaje.put("mensaje", "Usuario creado exitosamente");
            return ResponseEntity.ok(mensaje);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mensaje.clear();
            mensaje.put("error", "Error al crear el usuario: " + e.getMessage());
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(mensaje);
        }
    }
```

y el metodo upload.

```
public String uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        // Verificar si el archivo está vacío
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            return "Archivo no válido";
        }

        try {
            // Obtener el nombre original del archivo
            String originalFileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());

            // Generar un nombre de archivo único usando el nombre original y la marca de
            // tiempo actual
            String uniqueFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "_" + originalFileName;

            // Construir la ruta completa del archivo dentro de la carpeta "upload"
            String filePath = uploadDir + File.separator + uniqueFileName;

            // Guardar el archivo en la carpeta especificada
            file.transferTo(new File(filePath));

            // Devolver la ruta donde se guarda el archivo
            return filePath;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Manejar cualquier error que ocurra durante el proceso de carga
            return "Error al cargar el archivo";
        }
```

y la prueba en postman.

[image: prueba_postman]